# Rich push notification not working

Tags: ios, rich-notifications

We need to implement rich notification in current application with audio, video, image, gif.

I have implemented everything and its working fine.
And today started test some more push notification, but nothing works..

Similar issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61774

Normal notifications without mutable-content work fine.
Why its not working when adding mutable-content key to payload?

As far as I tested, there is no problem with certificate side..
I am using NotificationService extension to show media attachment

Any idea?

My payload looks like below:

```
{  
   "aps":{  
      "alert":{  
         "body":"On my way to searching humanity….. Did u see that?",
         "title":"God!!!"
      },
      "mutable-content":1,
      "category":"imageIdentifier"
   },
   "pic_url":"https://umad.com/img/2016/5/big-bear-wallpaper-background-12353-12796-hd-wallpapers.jpg",
   "mediaType":"image"
}
```

I am using APNS online tester https://pushtry.com/

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the problem, when `"mutable-content":1` is set the service extension gets called. You can modify the payload in service extension, the possible cause might be you forgot to add the `UNNotificationExtensionCategory` in `info.plist` of service extension

[image]

The payload looks perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

usernotification only used for local notification, not remote.
but you can received notification userinfo body, and sent local usernotification.
there is  a usernotification experience
http://www.jianshu.com/p/e4e9cb61eac9

Comment: thanks for response...we can use it for both, pls refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1